# Can I pass default parameter values to object properties in a PropertyGrid

Tags: vb.net

I have a custom class whose properties are exposed for view and editing using a PropertyGrid.

Some of the properties in the custom class are parameterised, i.e.

```
    Public Overridable Property NumUnits(pScenario As String, pPeriod As String) As Double
```

How can I pass default property parameters via the PropertyGrid to enable viewing and editing the object properties at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is to declare the parameters as Optional.

```
Public Overridable Property NumUnits(Optional pScenario As String = "1", Optional pPeriod As String = "2") As Double
```

Comment: Thanks - but the parameterised property doesn't show up in the PropertyGrid at all.